# Is there a specific notation to denote which angle is the orthogonal angle of a right triangle?

Tags: geometry, notation, soft-question, triangles, convention

If an exercise says "the right triangle $ABC$" is there an order of the letters to signify which angle is the orthogonal angle? For example

$ABC$ is a right triangle means $\hat B=90$ degrees

$BAC$ is a right triangle means $\hat A=90$ degrees

etc.

Comment: I've seen occasions where a right triangle written as $ABC$ has either $\angle BAC$ or $\angle ABC$ right angled. I've not seen the third happening. In the context of textbooks that introduce angles (I'd say a sixth or seventh grade textbook?) it is *specified*, either via a diagram (where the right angle is shown via a small box on the angle) or explicitly stated, that a certain vertex is the vertex of the right angle. I'm not sure that any standard notation exists.

Comment: One can, however, think about questions where it doesn't matter which exact angle is the right angle. (Or those where enough additional information is given, so that you can *deduce* which angle is the right angle.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In text, one convention is to use
$\quad\angle ABC=\angle\theta=\pi=90^\circ.\quad$ In the case of $\angle ABC$ the letter in the middle is generally the vertex containing the angle. (Think of $x=AB, y=BC, z=AC).\quad$
In drawing, it is common to put a small square inside the "figure" as shown in the crude image below.

[image]